# JPA - Join on same table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got this request :

```
TypedQuery<ParamGenerauxExternes> q = entityMgr
            .createQuery("SELECT p FROM ParamGenerauxExternes p "
                    + "WHERE EXISTS "
                    + "(SELECT q FROM ParamGenerauxExternes q "
                    + "WHERE q.key.origine = :pOrigine "
                    + "AND q.key.typeParam LIKE :pTypeParametreBis "
                    + "AND p.key.sousType LIKE CONCAT('%',q.libelleParam) "
                    + "AND q.actif = 'Y') "
                    + "ORDER BY p.libelleParam", ParamGenerauxExternes.class)
            //.setParameter("pTypeParametre", "REL_TO_HOUSEHOLD")
            .setParameter("pOrigine", pOrigineGrc)
            .setParameter("pTypeParametreBis", "GRC_HOUSEHOLD_TYPE_P%");
```

But it doesn't work, I got this error message that tell a prenthesis is missing :

```
GRAVE: EJB Exception: : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

The generated SQL by JPA has a parenthesis after the second select :

```
select
    paramgener0_.CODE_PARAM as CODE1_2823_,
    paramgener0_.ORIGINE as ORIGINE2823_,
    paramgener0_.SOUS_TYPE as SOUS3_2823_,
    paramgener0_.TYPE_PARAM as TYPE4_2823_,
    paramgener0_.ACTIF as ACTIF2823_,
    paramgener0_.LIBELLE_PARAM as LIBELLE6_2823_ 
from
    FOA_PARAM_GEN_EXTERNE paramgener0_ 
where
    exists (
        select
            (paramgener1_.CODE_PARAM,
            paramgener1_.ORIGINE,
            paramgener1_.SOUS_TYPE,
            paramgener1_.TYPE_PARAM) 
        from
            FOA_PARAM_GEN_EXTERNE paramgener1_ 
        where
            paramgener1_.ORIGINE=? 
            and (
                paramgener1_.TYPE_PARAM like ?
            ) 
            and (
                paramgener0_.SOUS_TYPE like '%'||paramgener1_.LIBELLE_PARAM
            ) 
            and paramgener1_.ACTIF='Y'
    ) 
order by
    paramgener0_.LIBELLE_PARAM
```

I don't know why hibernate add a parenthesis after the second `select` ? Please if you know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

That query fails on Oracle but passes on, for example, Postgres. If you are using Oracle database, try setting Oracle SQL dialect to your JPA provider.
[Hibernate SQL Dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects)